# How to add a file with CRLF Characters in git

Tags: git

I am a newbie to git.

In my project,i am supposed to add a file(which will be used in a integration test) to git repo, which contains CRLF characters.

But when i do "git add ", git is giving me a warning saying.. "CRLF would be replaced by LF .."

But, i don't want to git to strip these CRLF characters.

How to make git not to convert the CRLF to LF ?

Comment: Why don't you want to strip the CRLF characters?

Comment: What operating system are you running? And what is the output of `git config core.autocrlf`?

Comment: I have a test which uses FixCRLF utility, that operates on a shell script with CRLF characters, and after the execution, it should remove the CRLF characters.

Comment: Are you working on windows?

Comment: No i am not, its mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need that a file should be checked out with a crlf eol, the now good practice is to use a `.gitattributes` file with `text eol=crlf` for this type of file.

See https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#per-repository-settings

Comment: Sorry about that, I shouldn't be accusing people. :/ Anyway, your answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: No problem. I understand, I feel exactly the same when some people downvote too easily and that I really don't understand why. I personally never downvote. I prefer to express myself by upvoting...

Comment: Hi Philippe, can i have only one .gitattributes file per  git repo? I dont want the crlf settings to impact all other projects. Can i have ".gitattributes" file anywhere in the repository? If that is possible, i would want to keep the file in the directory where file with crlf characters are there.

Comment: Yes, you can have one per repository that's even the goal of this file. And yes you could put it where you want and it will apply only to this folder and subfolder .

Comment: No, my question is can i have one .gitattributes file at root level of the proeject and, another .gitattributes file at some child directory . And, will the child .gitattributes file overwrite the root level .gitattributes file when we are the child directory context?

Comment: Yes. (but this comment should be at least 15 characters)